# How to authorize mobile apps with a third party by oauth BUT connect to my service, not the 3rd party

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, oauth-2.0

My app is architected as follows: I have a web service (running on GAE, not very relevant to this question) and the data that this service contains is made available through a website and through mobile and desktop apps.

Currently, the user authenticates to the website via Google ClientLogin and the apps authenticate/get authorized via GAE's built-in oauth provider. (OAuth is being used here mostly for authentication, my app doesn't actually use any external data via OAuth other than the user's unique ID and email address.)

What I'd like to do is expand the number of services that users can use to login. Because of the complicating factor of the apps, it seems I need OAuth. But I can't really properly conceptualize how this flow should go.

Lets take Facebook as an example. When a mobile app goes through the Facebook oauth flow and acquires an access token, this isn't enough - because its my service, not the app, that actually needs to talk to facebook to retrieve contact info and a unique user ID. This leads me to think that the OAuth process needs to happen in the context of my service, and not the mobile app. My service then becomes the consumer and Facebook the oauth providor, and the service holds on to the oauth access token, this happens when a user sets up their account for the first time.

If this is the correct approach, where does that leave authentication for the apps? What happens when the user already has an account and installs a fresh instance of a mobile app? I imagine also going through the oauth process, matching up credentials with the data already stored by my service, and then issuing my own "access token" to the app from the service, to authorize that instance of the app. This seems convoluted and hackish.

I'm sure I can't be the only person who is in effect "borrowing" the account system of a third party for a mobile app with a backend, but I really don't see what the proper way to do this is.

What am I not seeing and/or getting conceptually wrong?

Comment: *Crickets* I feel like I might have formulated this question incorrectly. If so, please let me know. Otherwise, I'll answer my own question here... eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few colleagues and I once did a project quite similar in nature, back in university. We authenticated our users through either Facebook or Foursquare, using their respective OAuth APIs.

The native Android version of the app opened up a `WebView` with the OAuth provider's start page, which redirected back to our service after authentication. Then our service did a request for the OAuth token from the OAuth provider (Foursquare has some [pretty simple instructions](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html)). When we got that token, we set up a session using cookies, which we could access from the app.

To validate sessions, we just checked whether the access token was still valid with the provider. We also used the respective providers' unique user IDs to distinguish users.

So yes, what worked for us is: Make the app authenticate & authorise your *service*, not the app itself.

Comment: So, your app was storing these cookies and using them to authenticate to the service, and you would match up the cookie to the appropriate oauth token on your service? Is that any different than just generating a guid and handing that to the app?

Comment: Exactly, the app was using those stored cookies (containing encrypted IDs etc.) to authenticate to the service, which would then talk to the OAuth providers (to check, whether the token was still valid).
You could also use some kind of GUID, but you need to make it difficult to impersonate that app, e.g. have something that only the server knows to verify against.

Comment: Thankfully the app isn't dealing with particularly sensitive data in my case. But still, this approach makes sense but seems a little too "roll your own"ish. Its a solution, but I wonder if this is the consensus approach to this issue.