# OAuth2 "social login" flow (allow OAuth2 authentication via Facebook/Twitter): are there any examples/literature?

Tags: ios, api, ios5, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm developing a native mobile app for a custom, web-based social network app. We're building a REST API to communicate with the web server, and we've chosen OAuth2 as the authentication method (the `grant_type=password` flow).

The web-app allows users to login and signup using external services (ie. Facebook and Twitter). We need to allow the same also on the mobile app. The question is: how can we do that?

The Pinterest mobile app is able to manage the situation (see attached image). What is the flow that's been used here?

[image: Pinterest Login View]

Do they behave like a classical OAuth-powered app (the mobile app acting as OAuth client directly with the Facebook API?). If so, then how can the mobile app be authenticated with the   Pinterest server? Is it passing the Facebook OAuth access token as credentials?

Graphical representation of the problem (see the `????`-labeled arrow):

```
Website API                 Mobile app                    Facebook OAuth

  +                           +                               +
  |                           |                               |
  |                           |       /oauth2/token           |
  |                           +------------------------------>|
  |                           |                               |
  |                           |       OAuth Access Token      |
  |                           |<-----------------------------+|
  |                           |                               |
  |           ????            |                               |
  |- - - - - - - - - - - - - -|                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |    OAuth Access Token     |                               |
  |+------------------------->|                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |   API Usage (w/ token)    |                               |
  |+------------------------->|                               |
  |<-------------------------+|                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |+------------------------->|                               |
  |<-------------------------+|                               |
  |                           |                               |
  |           ...             |                               |
  +                           +                               +
```

**Update:** [This question is quite similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154108/ios-and-server-oauth-strategy) to mine.. If this is the right path to follow, then the second+third step (the transmission of the Facebook token to our custom API, plus the validation of the token itself) couldn't be an additional OAuth2 grant type (ie. `facebook_token`)?

Comment: What about proxying all API requests and modifying urls, headers and request params with your ones?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing exactly the same problem. Did you find a working solution to do that? thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the fb access token you just retrieved at your mobile device. (can be any other provider). Send it to your server to a login/register/both web service. At the server side you can check who's the user by using the fb sdk and the access token, login the user and send him the cookie/session.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a iOS dev, but I'm currently developing a similar workflow in a .NET environment, using the open-source DotNetOpenAuth library. Maybe having a look at it can help.

First: the authentication methodology depends on the providers you want to support.

A few readings that may clarify:
http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing
http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/
http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/openid-and-oauth-using-dotnetopenauth-in-asp-net-mvc/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996124/how-to-authorize-mobile-apps-with-a-third-party-by-oauth-but-connect-to-my-servi

Generic authentication workflow:
1. The web application starts by presenting an area that allows the user to select between various OpenID / OAuth providers. 
2. Your application redirects to the provider’s server (after possible adding some application information to the post data -- see specific provider's API reference for details). Both OpenID and OAuth use a series of redirects to get the user authenticated. The key is that the authentication occurs on the provider’s site and that’s where the passwords are stored. 
3. The user logs in the selected provider, then a new redirection to your site occurs (via a callback URL mechanism).
4. This redirect includes information about the authenticated user that is supplied by the OpenID / OAuth providers. At minimum the redirect supplies a ‘username’ back to your application.
5. Use this information to verify whether the authenticated user can enter your site.

Comment: Thanks Gianni, but the problem here is not with the web app acting as an OAuth client with Facebook: that is all classical, documented stuff. My question is about a mobile app that wants to use a custom API, but needs to authenticate to it NOT with a direct OAuth connection, but through a third-party OAuth authorizer (i.e. Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

Stefano

We use StackMob for this.  It works very well and is very simple to implement.

The StackMob SDK offers OAUTH2 security and authentication via Facebook and Twitter.

**Update**: [StackMob no longer exists as of May 2014](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2014/02/12/paypal-owned-stackmob-shut-may-11-team-can-focus-mobile-payment-technology/)

Comment: It would be kind of you to explain *where* and *how* the OP could use this SDK for or why you think this does *answer* any of his questions.

Comment: Yeah, thanks radesix, I can see their API [supports calls to create and login users using Facebook](https://stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/User-Authentication-API) but I can't find anything related to OAuth2. Sure, they seem to also support the OAuth2 protocol, but not to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Stefano, I'm not sure why this won't solve your problem.  StackMob uses OAUTH 2 as you are requesting.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer doesn't address the "How" is this particular authentication flow handled by StackMob within the OAuth2 protocol.

Comment: Stefano, your question was "The web-app allows users to login and signup using external services (ie. Facebook and Twitter). We need to allow the same also on the mobile app. The question is: how can we do that?" The answer I posted answers your question. Using StackMob allows the user to sign in via FB or Twitter which then gives you a token upon successful authentication.  When you drive a car you don't need to know how every part of the motor works.  You just need to operate the wheel, gas, and mirrors.  Why do you care HOW StackMob is doing this in the background? Please award the points.

Comment: @radesix, don't take it personally, but the question is how to "allow login via Facebook on a mobile app **to authorize the user in a secondary OAuth API**". StackMob has nothing to do with an OAuth2 flow :)

Comment: Updated the question title to be more explicit :)

Comment: @Stefano, no offense taken; however, StackMob DOES have something to do with an OAuth2 Flow.  StackMob allows you to login via Facebook or Twitter.  Once logged in you get an OAuth Token that can be passed to another API.  In fact, we built the login screen to look pretty much just like the screenshot you posted.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question in any way!

Answer (score 0):

Create different OAuth Client IDs for your social login providers.

**Example:**

Facebook -- Client ID #1
Twitter -- Client ID #2

---

Create your public routes for you social flows.

**Example:**

http://www.test.com/auth/facebook/
http://www.test.com/auth/facebook/callback/

On success of the social provider callback, you'll need to programmatically fetch the data from your datastore for the user in question then generate the **Access Token** with whatever predefined scope you want to grant for the **Client ID** in question.

---

In the case that you had a 3rd party directly attempting to interface with your own customers by attempting to use your API, it's going to have to be a 2-step process.

First they'd (the customer) have to go through the social login process as previously explained.

Then on the successful social provider callback you'd need to display an interface (web-based probably) to the customer allowing them to accept/deny the scope of rights being requested by the 3rd party. On the initial social login bit, you'd have to obviously pass a long or store the scope being requested by the 3rd party to pass it long for the social provider callback step.